# Error installing virtualenv on Mac OS 10.6

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, virtualenv

When I try to install [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) on my local machine running OS 10.6.4, I get the following:

```
Searching for virtualenv
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
Reading http://virtualenv.openplans.org
Best match: virtualenv 1.5.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.5.1.tar.gz#md5=3daa1f449d5d2ee03099484cecb1c2b7
Processing virtualenv-1.5.1.tar.gz
Running virtualenv-1.5.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/Ej/EjJBMhPjFSWPq+RuE6ubhE+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-lZp_Mm/virtualenv-1.5.1/egg-dist-tmp-vC_6xR
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.*' found under directory 'docs/_templates'
Adding virtualenv 1.5.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing virtualenv script to /usr/local/bin
error: /usr/local/bin: Permission denied
```

**Any thoughts on how I can remedy the error at the end?**

```
error: /usr/local/bin: Permission denied
```

Looking at my /usr/local directory, there is no /bin subdirectory. Any help would be great appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I have a /user/local/bin. I use macports python which puts things under /usr/local. So you must provide all the details. It is my understanding that you can drop this file virtualenv any where on path and you can use it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MacPorts, but just looked it up -- sounds like good stuff. Would you recommend that over virtualenv? Also, I already use rvm for Ruby, so would MacPorts affect that at all?

Comment: (By default, MacPorts installs in /opt/local not /usr/local.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have root permission to install into /usr/local/bin.  If you are using the `easy_install` command, do:

```
$ sudo easy_install virtualenv
```

Comment: I was about to say don't use sudo. But that only works on a vanilla OS X install, once you have sudo'd once, you will always have to sudo. Have a look at homebrew instead of macports: it can manage all your external stuff (including python), and without sudo.

Comment: The OP's question has nothing to do with MacPorts.  Homebrew is fine but there's nothing inherently bad about using sudo or using MacPorts.